# List loaded libraries of a process on FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, dynamic-loading, processes

How can I list all loaded libraries of a process in FreeBSD? On Linux I can use `/proc`

```
cat /proc/$pid/maps
```

on Solaris there is `pldd`

```
pldd $pid
```

For FreeBSD `/proc` also works:

```
cat /proc/$pid/map
```

however, `/proc` is not mounted by default. As this is used in an autodetection tool on customers' systems, I'm looking for something (tool or file) that works out of the box. I'm assuming there must be an additional interface to process data on FreeBSD because `top` works even without mounted `/proc`.

Comment: Pldd on Solaris works based on `/proc`, I would assume that you cannot find a non-/proc based method on FreeBSD either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[procstat](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?procstat) is your friend.

You get the info for a specific `pid` using:

```
procstat -v $pid
```

Or if you want for all processes then simply:

```
procstat -va
```

It yields an output like this:

```
$ procstat -v 61303
  PID              START                END PRT  RES PRES REF SHD   FL TP PATH
61303           0x400000           0x438000 r-x   46   47   2   0 CN-- vn /usr/local/bin/ksh
61303           0x638000           0x63c000 rw-    4    4   1   0 CN-- df
61303        0x800638000        0x800655000 r-x   29   30 204   0 CN-- vn /libexec/ld-elf.so.1
61303        0x800655000        0x800675000 rw-   23   23   1   0 CN-- df
61303        0x800855000        0x800857000 rw-    2    2   1   0 CN-- df
61303        0x800857000        0x8009cd000 r-x  293  329 218 102 CN-- vn /lib/libc.so.7
61303        0x8009cd000        0x800bcd000 ---    0    0   1   0 CN-- df
61303        0x800bcd000        0x800bd9000 rw-   12    0   1   0 C--- vn /lib/libc.so.7
61303        0x800bd9000        0x800c03000 rw-    8    8   1   0 CN-- df
61303        0x801000000        0x801800000 rw-   26   26   1   0 C--- df
61303     0x7ffffffdf000     0x7ffffffff000 rw-    3    3   1   0 C--D df
61303     0x7ffffffff000     0x800000000000 r-x    1    1 208   0 ---- ph
```

You see the shared libraries (and the binary itself) under `PATH`